# Silencing broken pipe errors (`[Errno 32] Broken pipe`) in python with WSGI+Pyramid

Tags: wsgi, python-3.4

I have a rather simple, naive Python/WSGI/Pyramid web-server.

It's run using `wsgiref.simple_server.make_server()`, on a server built using `pyramid.config.Configurator().make_wsgi_app()`. This server works fine.

However, the application it's serving has a *lot* of javascript image mouseover popups. If you run the mouse across the page, it can generate 20+ image requests. This is fine as well (It's an internal thing, not a lot of users).

However, doing so causes the server to emit something like half a dozen error tracebacks:

```
10.1.1.4 - - [25/Apr/2014 01:56:42] "GET /*SNIP* 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.1.1.4', 18338)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 333, in send_headers
    self._write(bytes(self.headers))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 391, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 306, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 332, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 345, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 666, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 126, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I understand *why* I'm getting broken pipe errors (the request for the image is canceled before the image has fully transfered, because the mouseover popup has closed), and it seems harmless.

However, I have no idea how to silence this traceback. There are thousands of them in my logs, and it makes debugging actual errors a nightmare. I don't care that I'm getting broken pipe errors, how can I catch them and swallow them silently?

It seems like `wsgiref.simple_server.make_server()` installs an internal handler that catches `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`, prints the traceback, and then swallows the error. I've tried wrapping the `run_server()` call in a try-except clause, and it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: The wsgiref server should never be used in a production setup. If you want something more reliable use a production grade WSGI server.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton - I have no idea what I'm doing. This is the first time I've used Pyramid, WSGI anything, or Python3 at all.

Comment: Also, while I don't doubt it's not "production" grade, what exactly does that actually mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up just switching to using the [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) [WSGI Server](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/refman/_cpserver.html). It doesn't suffer from the broken pipe log issues, and is probably far more robust as well.

It also uses a threadpool, so it's more performant as well (multiple requests aren't blocking!).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a straightforward way for achieving this, however, you can always do some monkey patching:

```
from wsgiref.handlers import BaseHandler
import sys


def ignore_broken_pipes(self): 
    if sys.exc_info()[0] != BrokenPipeError: BaseHandler.__handle_error_original_(self)

BaseHandler.__handle_error_original_ = BaseHandler.handle_error
BaseHandler.handle_error = ignore_broken_pipes
```

You will not see these annoyances after running this code somewhere in the beginning anymore.

For me, it looks like a bug somewhere in `wsgiref` implementation of `BaseHandler`:

```
def handle_error(self):
    """Log current error, and send error output to client if possible"""
    self.log_exception(sys.exc_info())
    if not self.headers_sent:
        self.result = self.error_output(self.environ, self.start_response)
        self.finish_response()
    # XXX else: attempt advanced recovery techniques for HTML or text?
```

if `BrokenPipeError` is handled by this method, `finish_response` crashes. Why do we ever want to finish response if pipe is broken? Where the data is sent to?